# Archlinux, move files to a different partition

Tags: partition, fstab

During the installation I *thought* I had generated the correct `fstab`, but now, after `cp` complains that the filesystem is full, I discover that `fstab` is **empty**.

I have this configuration:

```
# lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   238M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   1.9G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  23.3G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0 207.5G  0 part
```

But this is absolutely not what I want. I'd like to mount `/dev/sda1` as `/boot` and `/dev/sda4` as `/home/user`. `/dev/sda2` is swap.

The **problem** is that I already added a ton of files in `/home/user`, all of which went in `/dev/sda3`, because that one was the only one mounted.

How do I fix this?

I could boot from a live cd, mount the partitions, run `genfstab`, but then? Where do my files under `/home/user` go? Is it safe?

Should I move all my `home` content into a temporary directory, mount `/dev/sda4` and copy everything back?

Comment: your files are in the sda3 so changing `fstab` by itself won't **move** the files. You could `mkdir /home.new`; `mount /home.new /dev/sda4`; `mv /home/user /home.new`; `umount /home.new`; `rmdir /home`; `mv /home.new /home`; `mount /dev/sda4 /home`; and then edit `fstab` to mount `/home`.

Comment: @bdowning: Ah, thank you for confirming what I was thinking. At which point should I run `genfstab`, at the end, after having mounted the right `/home`?

Comment: @bdowning: Since I don't think there is a better way to do it, if you make an answer out of your comment, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Well it didn't let me use `mv` because it was an inter-device operation, so I had to `cp` first and then `rm`. But now everything's ok!

Comment: I made this as comment rather than an answer because it's not a general answer to a general problem encountered by many, but rather a specific prob encountered by you.

Comment: Oh, so you say we should leave the question unanswered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files are in the sda3 partition, so changing fstab by itself won't move the files.
You could (among several alternatives)

```
mkdir /home.new
mount /dev/sda4 /home.new 
cp -a /home/user /home.new
umount /home.new
rf -fr /home
mv /home.new /home
mount /dev/sda4 /home
```

then edit fstab to include `/home` `/dev/sda4`

Comment: Just a typo in the first mount! Argument order should be reversed. :)